# How to allow step in disabled input number

Tags: html, input, numbers, step

I want to have a disabled input number, but I want to be allowed to use the arrows to round it. How can I do it?

```
<input name="deroga" type="number" class="form-control" step=".01" value="127.05" disabled>
```

Thank you

Comment: disabled means you cant interact it it at all so you cant interact with the arrows

Comment: And How I can "hack it"?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<input name="deroga" type="number" class="form-control" step=".01" value="127.05" onkeydown="return false" >
```